# IllegalArgumentException on Worklight Connect from Native Android API

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using the Native Android API with Worklight 6.0.0.1 with the simulator on latest Android.

When connecting via https to the Worklight Server, I'm seeing the stack trace below in response to the initial request to connect to our production worklight server which resides behind a datapower gateway.

Tried connecting via a TCPMon proxy to sniff the network traffic (proxy on http, server on https) and found that this made the problem go away, while direct calls to the server continue to experience the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a known defect, and it is being fixed. You have to use a port that is not port 80 for the public Worklight port. This is why it worked with the proxy, because the Worklight application does not connect to the Worklight server directly.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer applies. We're connecting over https and have specified port 443.  Is there a similar problem affecting the default port for the https protocol?

Comment: I just checked, and it seems that it occurs when a port is not explicitly specified (either 80 or 443), so the fix should be the same.